# slider before and after map Dash

Tags: plotly-dash

how do i make a before and after slider on a map with dash?
https://dash.gallery/american-commute/detailed

I am quite new to dash and would like to apply it on my chart.
investigate without much success.

would I have to create my own component?
I would like to avoid creating it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to dash, but I think your solution could be CSS:
With the `style` or `className` attribute in the html elements in your dash layout, you can change the css.
And with CSS you can position your slider anywhere you want, also above the map.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp